# Error in my flutter project when i hit button to add newtransaction in list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

**I am passing a function pointer from the user transaction class to the new transaction class . Function similarly only do take two argument string title and double amount, In new transaction class in button function Onpressed string is fine but double type argument cause error**

**user transaction code is here**

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../modals/transactions.dart';
import 'new_transaction.dart';
import 'transaction_list.dart';

class UserTransactions extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserTransactions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserTransactionsState createState() => _UserTransactionsState();
}

class _UserTransactionsState extends State<UserTransactions> {
  final List<TranSaction> _userTransactions = [
    TranSaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    TranSaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'Weekly Groceries',
      amount: 16.53,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTx = TranSaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
        TransactionList(_userTransactions),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**New Transaction class code of flutter is**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  //NewTransaction({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //@override
  //State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
  final Function addTx;
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  NewTransaction(this.addTx, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Title',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                  )),
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   inputtitle = value;
              // },
              controller: titleController,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Amount',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
              //One of this method to save value in a field but we try another method
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   inputamount = value;
              // },
              controller: amountController,
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //using lisnter mentod i confirm this way my value is save or not
                  // print(inputtitle);
                  // print(inputamount);
                  // print(titleController.text);
                  addTx(
                    titleController.text,
                    double.parse(amountController.text),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Add Transaction',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Everything works for me, what is your error?

Comment: The string is not subtype of double exception occur

Comment: String is not a subtype of double

Comment: Do you input your amount with dot or with comma (e.g. 9.99 or 9,99), because comma will not parse into double? And can you provide your `TransactionList` code also?